# Add Spinning Wheel Progress Bar In Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I try to add spinning wheel progress bar in my module in android.but its not working.

By click on send button i want to add the spinning wheel.tell me where to add this and how to add.

my code is:

Fragment send job.java

```
public class FragmentSendJob extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    // this Fragment will be called from MainActivity

    TextView newmember,forgot,view;

    EditText uedit,pedit; 
    Vibrator vibe;
    String euid,epass;

    String name,pass;
    String status_key;

    private static MyDialog dialog1;

    Bitmap bitmap1, bitmap2,bitmap3;
    Bitmap[] bitmap;
    String[] driver_details;
    private byte imageInByte1[],imageInByte2[],imageInByte3[] ;
    private Context mContext;
    private String mname,mobile,desc;

    public String advertisement_count;
    private Button submit,cancel;
    private EditText ename,mobno,picktime,unit,street,suburb,destination,fare,city;
    private Spinner state,group;
    private ViewGroup vgroup ;

// name of the para meter on send job module
    private String sename,smobno,spicktime,sunit,sstreet,ssuburb,sstate, ssendjob,scity,sdestination,sfare,sgroup,login_token;

    private static FragmentDialog dialog;
    private  SendJobDataBase db; 
    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private Typeface ftype;
     private SharedPreferences pref1,pref;
    String latitude,longitude;
    public String job_id;



    public FragmentSendJob(){}

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sendjob_fragment, container, false);
        pref1=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LocDetails", getActivity().MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        pref=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Driver", getActivity().MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        login_token=pref.getString("login_token","login_token"); 
        latitude = pref1.getString("latitude","latitude"); 
        longitude = pref1.getString("longitude","longitude"); 

        ename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ename);
        mobno  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobno);
        picktime  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.picktime);
        unit  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
        street  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.street);
        suburb  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.suburb);
        destination  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.destination);
        state = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.state);
        fare=(EditText)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.fare);
        group = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.group);
        city  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.city);
        vgroup = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rel); 
        submit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    new SendJob().execute();
              /*  Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),GetCurrentLocation.class);
                startActivity(intent); 

                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+latitude+"***********");
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+longitude+"***********");*/


                }

            });



        cancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0, count = vgroup.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
                    View view = vgroup.getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof EditText) {
                        ((EditText)view).setText("");
                    }
                }

                }       
        });
//state spinner which represents different state by on click
        String[] mystate= new String[]{"New South Wales","Victoria","Queensland","Northern Territory","Western Australia","South Australia"};       
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.listrow, mystate);

        state.setAdapter(adapter);  

                state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                scity =  state.getSelectedItem().toString();

                   String s1=arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                        if(s1.equals("New South Wales"))
                            city.setText("Sydney");
                        else if(s1.equals("Victoria"))
                            city.setText("Melbourne");
                        else if(s1.equals("Queensland"))
                            city.setText("Brisbane");
                        else if(s1.equals("Northern Territory"))
                            city.setText("Darwin");
                        else if(s1.equals("Western Australia"))
                            city.setText("Perth");
                        else if(s1.equals("South Australia"))
                            city.setText("Adelaide");

                             }
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });


                String[] mygroups= new String[]{"My Group","My Secondary group","Everyone"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                        R.layout.listrow, mygroups);
                group.setAdapter(adapters);

                group.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int pos, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                ssendjob = group.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                                //gender.setText(setgender);
                            }

                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
        return rootView;
       }
```

//web services to get data

```
    private class SendJob extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try 
                {

                System.out.print("***** login token *****"+login_token);
                JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                sename = ename.getText().toString();
                smobno = mobno.getText().toString();
                spicktime = picktime.getText().toString();
                sunit = unit.getText().toString();
                sstreet = street.getText().toString();
                ssuburb = suburb.getText().toString();
                sstate = state.getSelectedItem().toString();
                scity = city.getText().toString();
                sdestination = destination.getText().toString();
                sgroup = group.getSelectedItem().toString();
                sfare = fare.getText().toString();

                sename.replace("" ,"%20");
                smobno.replace("" ,"%20");
                spicktime.replace("" ,"%20");
                sunit.replace("" ,"%20");
                sstreet.replace("" ,"%20");
                sstate.replace("" ,"%20"); 
                ssuburb.replace("" ,"%20");
                scity.replace("" ,"%20");
                sdestination.replace("" ,"%20");
                sgroup.replace("" ,"%20");
                sfare.replace("" ,"%20");

                     job.put("name",sename);
                     job.put("mobile_no",smobno);
                     job.put("pickup_time",spicktime);
                     job.put("unit_no",sunit);
                     job.put("street_name",sstreet);
                     job.put("state",sstate);
                     job.put("suburb",ssuburb);
                     job.put("city",scity);
                     job.put("destination",sdestination);
                     job.put("group",sgroup);
                     job.put("fare",sfare);
                     job.put("latitude",latitude);
                     job.put("longitude",longitude);
                     job.put("status_key","2");
                     job.put("method","send_job");
                     job.put("login_token",login_token);

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(se);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Log.i("response", data);

                    System.out.println("response "+data);
                    String call;
                    call = data;

                                System.out.println("print me............."+call);

                                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                                Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                                /*JSONObject jobId= jo.getJSONObject("id");  
                                job_id=jobId.getString("id");*/


                                if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                                {

                                    DatabaseAdmin admin = new DatabaseAdmin(getActivity());
                                    try
                                    {
                                    admin.insert_user(smobno, sename, smobno, sdestination, sstate, "0", spicktime, sunit, sstreet, ssuburb, scity, sfare, sgroup);
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                                    alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) 
                                        {
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                            dialog.dismiss();

                            /*   Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),HandleData.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("pickupsuburb", ssuburb);
                                    intent.putExtra("destination", sdestination);
                                    startActivity(intent);*/


                                         }
                                    });
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            alert.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                                    alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();


                                        }
                                    });
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                                    {
                                        public void run() 
                                        {
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                            alert.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                            }
                            catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
            else
            {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                alert.setMessage("No Internet connection ");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) 
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();



                    }
                });
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
            }
                        return params;
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
                    {

                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                    }       
       }
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to `.show()` to your `Progress Dialog`

```
pDialog.show();
```

and implement `pDialog` in `onPreExecute()` in `AsyncTask` like so,

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait....");
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
    }
```

and `dismiss Progress Dialog` in  `onPostExecute(....)` like so,

```
               @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
                {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                }
```

Comment: I have added the code as you say.and its work well but spinner is not dismissed.